# How to enable Jaeger opentracing in WSO2-APIM 3.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, jaeger

I'm not able to get any tracing on Jaeger.

I did this configuration:

```
[apim.open_tracer]
remote_tracer.enable = true
remote_tracer.name = "jaeger"
remote_tracer.properties.hostname = "192.168.1.2"
remote_tracer.properties.port = "6831"
```

Should I keep the double quotes in the hostname and port ?
What is the correct port to use ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep double quotes as it is.

An issue has been identified similar to this [1] and has been fixed recently. Can you try to get the latest WUM updated API Manager 3.1.0 and try enabling Jaeger open tracing?

Alternatively, this issue will not occur when using "localhost" as the hostname.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7940

Comment: I'm using docker image. Do you know if the latest docker image have this fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Run Jager using the docker image as follows.

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 \
  -p 5775:5775/udp \
  -p 6831:6831/udp \
  -p 6832:6832/udp \
  -p 5778:5778 \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 14268:14268 \
  -p 14250:14250 \
  -p 9411:9411 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.18
```

Then add the following config to the deployment.toml.

```
[apim.open_tracer]
remote_tracer.enable = true
remote_tracer.name = "jaeger"
remote_tracer.properties.hostname = "localhost"
remote_tracer.properties.port = "6831"
```

Side Note: For zipkin you can use the following.

```
[apim.open_tracer]
remote_tracer.enable = true
remote_tracer.name = "zipkin"
remote_tracer.properties.hostname = "localhost"
remote_tracer.properties.port = "9411"
```